# DropdownList Values using RequiredFieldValidator in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to select any specific value from dropdownlist. Currently have YES and NO . If No is selected then should show an error message using Required Field Validator. There should be no error message when the value is selected as YES from dropdown

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [`InitialValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) of the `RequiredFieldValidator` to `NO`(if the value is the same as the text, otherwise use the appropriate value):

```
<asp:asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqYesNo" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="DropDownListYesNo"
    InitialValue="NO">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the value on which you want to show error message in *InitialValue* property of required field.

like this -

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="you have selected NO" ControlToValidate="YOURDropDownID" InitialValue="NO"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```